# How to Enable Images and links in RichTextBox (WPF)?

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, richtextbox

I have tried to copy content of a hidden webbrowser to RichTextBox thanks to an already posted question in *Stack Overflow* , this is my code

```
<WebBrowser Name="webBrowser1" helper:WebBrowserHelper.BindableSource="C:\Users\med\Desktop\cover.xhtml" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        <RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True" Name="richTextBox1" />
```

here is my code behind :

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dynamic document = webBrowser1.Document;
            document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
            document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);
            richTextBox1.Paste();

        }
```

the problem here is that when the Html page is displayed in my RichTextBox control , i cannot click on links to move to another page , also Images are not displayed ...
Any suggestion ?

The main objectif of this manipulation is to enable selection on my html content , because in web browser , i can't enable it and catch the start and end position of the selected text which is necessary to make highlights on Html Text (from the Epub File) [If i use the `textrange` and the user select a word and highlight it , this word will be highlight N times if it exists in duplication in this html file , but i want to highlight only the selected Portion) .
Is there any possible alternative for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable user interaction with hyperlinks in a `RichTextBox`, you need to set the [`RichTextBox.IsDocumentEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.isdocumentenabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to `true`.  Users will now be able to follow links with a Ctrl+Click:

```
<RichTextBox IsDocumentEnabled="True" />
```

If you mark the control as read only, they will be able to follow with just a Click:

```
<RichTextBox IsDocumentEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Having done that, it's still necessary to actually provide a callback when the user clicks the hyperlink.  Hyperlinks in a `RichTextBox` are contained in instances of the [`Hyperlink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.  This class has a [`RequestNavigate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink.requestnavigate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event, which does what you need.  You could set each event individually on each `Hyperlink`, but it's much, much easier to set it on the encompassing `RichTextBox`, and allow the routed event mechanism to bubble the `RequestNavigate` up to the text box.

You could do this in your code in the `OnLoaded` for your window:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.AddHandler(Hyperlink.RequestNavigateEvent, new RequestNavigateEventHandler(HyperLink_RequestNavigate));
    }

    void HyperLink_RequestNavigate(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Alternatively, you could do this in the XAML for your rich text box by using a default style for `Hyperlink` objects and providing the callback:

```
        <RichTextBox Name="richTextBox1" AcceptsTab="True" IsDocumentEnabled="True">
            <RichTextBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
                    <EventSetter Event="RequestNavigate" Handler="HyperLink_RequestNavigate" />
                </Style>
            </RichTextBox.Resources>
        </RichTextBox>
```

(Note - tested in Windows 7).

As far as displaying images goes, this simply works out of the box with `RichTextBox`.  If I create a Microsoft Word document containing some images, then copy and paste the entire document's content into an RTB, the included images show up.  If I copy a single image with Firefox by right-clicking on the image and choosing "Copy Image", then paste it into an RTB, it shows up.  However, copying and pasting from Word to an RTB uses [RTF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) as its [interchange format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dataformats.rtf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); maybe there's some problem with your HTML converter?

As an aside, it isn't easy to understand exactly what objects live inside a given `FlowDocument`.  The structure of what might be inside isn't well documented (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for an overview).  I have found the following debug utilities useful, they convert the `FlowDocument` to XAML and output it in a readable format:

```
public static class FlowDocumentHelper
{
    public static string ToFormattedXamlString(this FlowDocument doc)
    {
        if (doc == null)
            return null;
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.IndentChars = "    ";
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings);
        XamlWriter.Save(doc, xmlWriter);
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static string DebugFlowDocumentXaml(this FlowDocument doc)
    {
        var str = doc.ToFormattedXamlString();
        Debug.WriteLine(str);
        return str;
    }
}
```