# RichTextBox in LongListSelector: how to intercept click on HyperLink?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, richtextbox, longlistselector

I have the application - chat. For messages viewing used LongListSelector. Each message can contains BB-tags: B, U, I, URL, IMG, COLOR. It handled correctly with extented RichTextBox:

```
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace System.Windows.Controls
{
    public class RichTextViewer : RichTextBox
    {
        public const string RichTextPropertyName = "RichText";

        public static readonly DependencyProperty RichTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(RichTextPropertyName,
                                        typeof(string),
                                        typeof(RichTextBox),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(
                                            new PropertyChangedCallback
                                                (RichTextPropertyChanged)));

        public RichTextViewer()
        {
            IsReadOnly = true;
            Background = new SolidColorBrush { Opacity = 0 };
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
        }

        public string RichText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(RichTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RichTextProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void RichTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        {
            string xaml = "<Paragraph xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">" + ((string)dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue) + "</Paragraph>";
            xaml=xaml.Replace("\r", "");
            xaml = xaml.Replace("\n", "<LineBreak/>");
            xaml = Regex.Replace(xaml, "\\[b\\](.+?)\\[/b\\]", "<Bold>$1</Bold>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            xaml = Regex.Replace(xaml, "\\[i\\](.+?)\\[/i\\]", "<Italic>$1</Italic>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            xaml = Regex.Replace(xaml, "\\[u\\](.+?)\\[/u\\]", "<Underline>$1</Underline>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            xaml = Regex.Replace(xaml, "\\[color=(.+?)\\](.+?)\\[/color\\]", "<Span Foreground=\"$1\">$2</Span>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            xaml = Regex.Replace(xaml, "\\[img\\](.+?)\\[/img\\]", "<InlineUIContainer><Image Source=\"$1\" Stretch=\"None\" /></InlineUIContainer>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            xaml = Regex.Replace(xaml, "\\[img=(.+?)\\]", "<InlineUIContainer><Image Source=\"$1\" Stretch=\"None\" /></InlineUIContainer>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            xaml = Regex.Replace(xaml, "\\[url\\](.+?)\\[/url\\]", "<Hyperlink NavigateUri=\"$1\">$1</Hyperlink>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            xaml = Regex.Replace(xaml, "\\[url=(.+?)\\](.+?)\\[/url\\]", "<Hyperlink NavigateUri=\"$1\">$2</Hyperlink>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            ((RichTextBox)dependencyObject).Blocks.Clear();
            ((RichTextBox)dependencyObject).Blocks.Add(XamlReader.Load(xaml) as Paragraph);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Controls:RichTextViewer RichText="{Binding Message}" Width="350" />
```

It working well, but I need to intercept clicks on HyperLink tags and handle it with my application or open in browser (depend on URL). And I can't understand how to make it. I see three way to implement it:

1. Add Click="HyperlinkButton_Click" to every HyperLink tag. It doesn't work, I get the exception:

   XamlReader.Load() does not accept event handlers. Setting event 'System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink.Click' is not permitted.
2. Try to add event handler programmatically to every HyperLink after XamlReader.Load(). That's mean many handlers for every link (chat can contains many messages and one message can contains few links) in memory and I am not sure that is the good way.
3. Register custom URI scheme for my application and force all links to this scheme.

What is the way is possible and better in this case?

Comment: Does this, for Desktop WPF, not work?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379949/how-to-enable-images-and-links-in-richtextbox-wpf/25432047#25432047

Comment: @dbc, as I see, class Hyperlink have not RequestNavigateEvent field on Windows Phone 8.